# Bounding the cardinality of finite Index sets by the Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, cardinals

I am trying to find an estimate for the cardinality of indices with the upper bound beeing the Lebesgue Measure and to generalize the statement.

Let $0 \leq a < b < \infty$ and $n \in \mathbb{N},$ then
$$ card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \, a \leq i/n \leq b \rbrace \leq n \cdot \lambda([a,b]) +1,$$
where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue-Measure on $\mathbb{R}.$

Question 1: Are there situations, where the upper bound without the "+1" is correct?

Question 2: Let's say the set of interest changes from $\lbrace a \leq i/n \leq b \rbrace$ to an arbitrary (Lebesgue) measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^+_0.$ Does the inequation
$$ card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \,i/n \in A \rbrace \leq n \cdot \lambda(A) +1$$
stil hold?

Question 3: Is it true and possible to show, that
$$ 1/n \cdot card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \,i/n \in A \rbrace 
\rightarrow_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A)$$
Riemann-Sums seem to be inapplicable in this case.

Many thanks and best wishes!

Comment: You are simply writing $\lambda([a,b])$ to replace the simpler expression $b-a$.  Writing $b-a$ will help you to see the answers you are looking for.

Comment: (1) $[0,1]$ decided in $n$ pieces of equal size.

Comment: Question 2: The answer is no.  Just take $A= \Bbb Q$  and remember that $\lambda( \Bbb Q)=0$.

Comment: (3) is realted to the concept of [vague convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vague_topology). As you almost pointed out, if you has a continuous function $f$ with compact support in say, then interval $[-m,m]$ ($m\in\mathbb{N}$) and divide each subinterval $[j,j+1]$ ($-m\leq j<m$ in $n$ pieces of the same length, and evaluate the "Riemann sum" $\frac{1}{n}\sum_kf(k/n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^m_{-m}f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: (2) As Ramiro pointed out, things my go bad. That amounts to changing continuous function $f$ in my previous comment for functions with  discontinuities.

Comment: Question 3.  The answer is also no. Again take $A=\Bbb Q$. Then, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, 
$ 1/n \cdot card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \,i/n \in A \rbrace = \infty $ and $\lambda(A)=0$. So
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  1/n \cdot card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \,i/n \in A \rbrace = \infty \neq 0 = \lambda(A)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This became a little too long to be just a comment.

**Item 1**:
a. How many intervals of length $\frac{1}{n}$ can fit completely in $[a,b]$ under the condition that any two sub-intervals have at most one extreme point as intersection?  Answer:
$\lfloor n(b-a) \rfloor$, where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function.

b. How many of the extremes points of such intervals will be $[a,b]$?  Answer:  $\lfloor n(b-a) \rfloor +1$

So, we **would** have $ card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \, a \leq i/n \leq b \rbrace = \lfloor n(b-a) \rfloor +1$.

In this case, we will never have $\lfloor n(b-a) \rfloor +1 \leq n(b-a)$,  , because
$n(b-a) - \lfloor n(b-a) \rfloor < 1$.

c. However, the sub-intervals don't need to begin at $a$. So, if
$$ \min \left \{\frac{i}{n}:  \frac{i}{n} \geq a \right\} -a + b - \max \left \{\frac{i}{n}: \frac{i}{n} \leq b \right\} \geq \frac{1}{n} $$
we have enough room so that the space before the first sub-interval plus the space after the last sub-interval be big enough for one sub-interval, but useless because those spaces are not connected to each other.

So, if
$$ \min \left \{\frac{i}{n}:  \frac{i}{n} \geq a \right\} -a + b - \max \left \{\frac{i}{n}: \frac{i}{n} \leq b \right\} \geq \frac{1}{n} $$
since
$$ \min \left \{\frac{i}{n}:  \frac{i}{n} \geq a \right\} -a <\frac{1}{n} $$
and
$$ b - \max \left \{\frac{i}{n}: \frac{i}{n} \leq b \right\} < \frac{1}{n} $$
we will have:
$$ card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \, a \leq i/n \leq b \rbrace = \lfloor n(b-a) \rfloor  \leq n(b-a)$$

**Item 2**: The answer is no. Just take $A=\Bbb Q$
and remember that $\lambda(\Bbb Q)=0$.

**Item 3**:  The answer is also no. Again take $A=\Bbb Q$. Then, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$,
$ 1/n \cdot card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \,i/n \in A \rbrace = \infty $ and $\lambda(A)=0$. So
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  1/n \cdot card\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: \,i/n \in A \rbrace = \infty \neq 0 = \lambda(A)$$

Comment: Hello Ramiro, thanks for your answer and comments!

Comment: @fixfoxi , You are welcome. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actually answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and am very thankful. 
By accident I sent the message without adding my question: 

Regarding Item 1:
b. Am I right thinking that choosing a=1.9, b=3.3, n=3 generates a counterexample to the formula for $card \lbrace i \in \mathbb{N}: a \leq i/n \leq b \rbrace = \lfloor n(b-a) \rfloor+1$?
Since $\lfloor 3*(3.3 - 1.9 \rfloor = 4$. But only $i=6,7,8,9$ are possible?

Regarding Item 2 and 3: Thank you very much! This helps a lot.

Comment: @fixfoxi , You are right. Thanks. I update the answer in item 1. Please, take a look and let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Thank you for the Clarification!
I can follow and will accept your answer.
Do you agree, that the cardinality can be written as 
$$ card \lbrace i: a \leq i/n \leq b \rbrace = \lfloor n \cdot b \rfloor - \lceil n \cdot a \rceil +1$$?

Comment: @fixfoxi  , Yes , by considering the intervals $[0,b]$ and $[0, a]$.

Comment: Thank you very much!